# Jquery attribute not being added to div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div as follows

```
'<div class="ctrl-info-panel col-md-12 col-centered">'+
    '<h2>You do not have any projects created at the moment.</h2>'+
    '<div id="t1" style="display:inline-flex"  data-toggle="tooltip">'+
        '<p><a href="create_project.jag" class="cu-level2-btn btn-add-new-dark ' + appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets) + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Create Project"><span>Create Project</span></a></p>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>'
```

I am trying to add an attribute to `#t1` in the following function.

```
 function appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets) {
        var classAppend = '';
        if(noOfDatasets == 0) {
            $("#t1").attr('title','No datasets available');
            classAppend = 'cu-level-btn-disabled';  
        }
        return classAppend;
    }
```

But the attribute is not being added. I am not getting a text in the tooltip. what's the issue here?

Note that `noOfDatasets` is 0.

Comment: my guess is it has something to do with dynamically created object

Comment: i think your `noOfDatasets` are not 0 or your are passing wrong parameter.

Comment: Are you creating your div with jquery? Maybe jquery can't find the div `#t1` because it is dynamically created?

Comment: You should make example on jsbin, jsfiddle or any other for better feedback

Comment: Or you may have duplicate ids i.e. more than one #t1 elements

Comment: call the appendCreateprojctDsiabled method after **#t1** div is append in DOM. Then only the jQuery will get the element.

Comment: You need to first append your html then have to call this function so it can find id "#t1"

Comment: Debug the code, and make sure you can see the element. You can also put a breakpoint to check the "if" condition in Chrome dev tool

Comment: maybe you call your function before you append div to DOM

Comment: is ther anyway that i can manually apend this element to dom?

Comment: `attr` won't return dynamically modified elements. Instead of `attr` try to use `prop`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the issue in your code is the order is is executed.

When the function `appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets)` is executed, it looks for the element `$("#t1")`, which *does not exists* yet since the following string has not been added to the HTML document yet:

```
'<div class="ctrl-info-panel col-md-12 col-centered">'+
                                '<h2>You do not have any projects created at the moment.</h2>'+
                                '<div id="t1" style="display:inline-flex"  data-toggle="tooltip">'+
                                    '<p><a href="create_project.jag" class="cu-level2-btn btn-add-new-dark ' + appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets) + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Create Project"><span>Create Project</span></a></p>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'
```

As you may notice, the above code has the element `id="t1"`, which doesn't exists at the time the function `appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets)` is called.

Comment: How do i solve it? How can i make sure the element exists?

Answer (score 0):

You created the div here dynamicly in javascript, so you just have a string here. 
There is two way for you.

First you should write in on the page.

```
var htmlString = '<div class="ctrl-info-panel col-md-12 col-centered">'+
                            '<h2>You do not have any projects created at the moment.</h2>'+
                            '<div id="t1" style="display:inline-flex"  data-toggle="tooltip">'+
                                '<p><a href="create_project.jag" class="cu-level2-btn btn-add-new-dark ' + appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets) + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Create Project"><span>Create Project</span></a></p>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>';
function appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets) {

var classAppend = '';

    $("#aDivInYourPage").html(htmlString);//after register your div you can find your 't1' div. if not it will be undefuned for you. 

    if(noOfDatasets == 0) {
        $("#t1").attr('title','No datasets available');
        classAppend = 'cu-level-btn-disabled';  
    }
    return classAppend;
}
```

The other way is you can put a spetial character to your div like `{TitleAttribute}` and replace this with  your attribute like `title='No datasets available'`

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by parsed the string to HTML element.
Try this code.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  function appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets, divElement) {
    var classAppend = '';
    if (noOfDatasets == 0) {
      divElement.find("#t1").attr('title', 'No datasets available');
      classAppend = 'cu-level-btn-disabled';
    }
    return classAppend;
  }

  var divElement = '<div class="ctrl-info-panel col-md-12 col-centered">' +
                   '<h2>You do not have any projects created at the moment.</h2>' +
                   '<div id="t1" style="display:inline-flex"  data-toggle="tooltip">' +
                   '</div>' +
                   '</div>'
  divElement = $(divElement);
  var paraElement = '<p><a href="create_project.jag" class="cu-level2-btn btn-add-new-dark ' + appendCreateprojectDisabled(0, divElement) + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Create Project"><span>Create Project</span></a></p>'
  divElement.find("#t1").append($(paraElement));
  $(document.body).append(divElement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
var classAppend = "";
var classAppend =  appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets);
```

After making sure `classAppend` have some value; you can append your html wherever you want.

```
var html = '<div class="ctrl-info-panel col-md-12 col-centered">' +
        '<h2>You do not have any projects created at the moment.</h2>' +
        '<div id="t1" style="display:inline-flex"  data-toggle="tooltip">' +
        '<p><a href="create_project.jag" class="cu-level2-btn btn-add-new-dark ' + classAppend + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Create Project"><span>Create Project</span></a></p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
```

Use this piece of html wherever you want now. The below function is called first.

```
function appendCreateprojectDisabled(noOfDatasets) {
        var classAppend = '';
        if(noOfDatasets == 0) {
            $("#t1").attr('title','No datasets available');
            classAppend = 'cu-level-btn-disabled';  
        }
        return classAppend;
    }
```